# How to use cube.js to connect to specific redis

Tags: redis, cube.js

If I want to connect cube.js to my own built redis, what should I do.
I use `CUBEJS_REDIS_URL` which is claimed by [official  document](https://cube.dev/docs/deployment/overview#redis). So, for example, if my own redis port is 31.71.195.218.
Should I use write `CUBEJS_REDIS_URL=redis://31.71.195.218:6379/0` in my backend .env file? I use many combination like, `redis://31.71.195.218:6379`, `redis://31.71.195.218`, ecc.

However, they all show the following error message:

```
process in uncaughtException:  { Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1117:14)
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 6379 }
```

in my terminal. It seems that this environment variable  `CUBEJS_REDIS_URL` isn't used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think cube.js doesn't use your configuration in DEV mode, Try setting `CUBEJS_DEV_MODE=false` in your env file

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass the env variables into the Docker container. Please see this example in the documentation: https://cube.dev/docs/deployment/platforms/docker